# Razor MVC 3 Ajax returns 404

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a basic autocomplete via jquery AJAX, using Razor MVC 3 and Visual Studio 2012 (all of which I had never used before) My code is as follows

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $("#city").keyup(function () {
        var input = $(this).val();
        getCities(input);
    });
});

function getCities(input) {
    var serviceURL = $("#autocompleteURL").val();    
    var url =
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: {
                'guess': input
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('OK!!');    
            },
        });
}
```

Since i learned that it's not possible to use Razor syntax in a JS file, I'm getting the value from the view via a hidden input, like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="autocompleteURL" value="@Url.Action("AutoCompleteCity", "Controllers/SearchController")" />
```

Controller:

```
 public class SearchController: Controller
   {
       public ActionResult AutoCompleteCity(string guess)
        {
            //database stuff here
        }
   }
```

I don't know if I'm missing something else. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It needs to be `@Url.Action("AutoCompleteCity", "Search")` but do not add a hidden input. In the element with `id="city"`, add a data attribute using `data-url = "@Url.Action("AutoCompleteCity", "Search")"` and retrieve it using `var url = $(this).data(url);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention for the controller name is just the semantic name of the controller, not the file path.  Instead of this:

```
Url.Action("AutoCompleteCity", "Controllers/SearchController")
```

Try this:

```
Url.Action("AutoCompleteCity", "Search")
```

(Note also that you can use the debugging tools in your browser to examine the URL being used in the AJAX call.)